# Why does WebApplication.SendFile fail with "Reply type already set"?

Tags: delphi, intraweb, delphi-xe3

Steps:

1. I created a new IntraWeb application using the `IntraWeb Application Wizard`.
2. I put a TIWButton on the form.
3. I put this code in to the OnClick event handler:

`WebApplication.SendFile('D:\Temp\ClearAll.sql');`

Clicking on the button raises an exception of type `Exception` with the message `Reply type already set`.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Delphi is XE3 with IntraWeb XIV.

I tried the same with Deplhi 2007 (IntraWeb 9) and it works, so this seems to be a bug in IntraWeb XIV.

Can sombody please confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug as confirmed by 
Jackson Gomes:

> > I found out that this doesn't happen on XE2 with Intraweb XII. So it 
> >     seems to be a bug in Intraweb XIV or Delphi XE3.
>
> correct
>
> > In addition we know have a registered copy of Delphi XE3 and Intraweb 
> >     XIV still switches ports randomly (e.g. doesn't use the port I
> >     specified  in the server controller).
>
> We will check it... thanks

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77064